# getting wrong count of selected rows

Tags: php, mysql, count

```
function c_save( $a, $status, $b ) {
    global $db;
    $st = $db->query( "select count(id) from steps where cas = '" . $a . "' and status = '" . $status . "' and title = '" . $b . "'" );
    $count = $st->rowCount(); echo $count;
}
```

the echoed result - `1`

Manually checking the table (20 rows total) - there is no such a row having `cas = $a...` so the result should be `0`.

Comment: Your query will return a single row, that being the row containing the count of matching rows. If you instead change the query to `SELECT *...`, and get the `$st->rowCount()`, it should return 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function c_save($a, $status, $b){
    global $db;
    $st = $db->query("select id from steps where cas = '" . $a . "' and status = '" . $status . "' and title = '" . $b . "'");
    $count = $st->rowCount(); 
    echo $count;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you are performing the count at the query level. the result of your query is a single line containing maybe 20.
if you want to get the number of records ', you can just get the value returned by the query or do not count within sql to get the full resultset and let php make the count.